# PyUSB Can't find device

Tags: python, pyusb

I am running OS X 10.5 and am trying to connect to a USB device via PyUSB with the following code.

```
   import usb.core, time, usb

   dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x054c,idProduct=0x0155)
    if dev is None:
      raise ValueError('Device not found')           # if device not found report an error
```

Though the value error 'device not found' is thrown. OS X System Profiler denotes the devices product and vendor id as..

```
      EyeToy USB camera Namtai:

      Product ID: 0x0155
      Vendor ID: 0x054c  (Sony Corporation)
      Version: 1.00
      Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
      Manufacturer: Sony corporation
      Location ID: 0x06200000 / 3
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 500
```

**Solution**: Had to manual install libusb-1.0.8. Mac-ports didn't install libusb correctly.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, `usb.core.find()` only works when running the python interpreter (or script) with `sudo`. What worries me is that, if not ran with `sudo`, the library is not found, which doesn't happen in last Snow Leopard, any tips?

Comment: Interfacing with hardware requires 'sudo' privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew install of libusb helped for me

```
[sudo] brew install libusb
```

Answer (score 3):

Try enumerating your devices via PyUSB.  This example is from the docs to find all printers (device class 7):

```
printers = usb.core.find(find_all=True, bDeviceClass=7)
```

This should hopefully include your device and you can see what the fields actually are.  Your camera is probably class 0x0e or 0x10.

Comment: Thanks, though still returns no devices... $sudo python eye.py
Output: []

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had installed libusb via MacPorts but was using python installed via pyenv.

Make sure you use the python version installed via MacPorts.

```
which python
```

The above code should tell you the location of python version you are using. It should say `/opt/local/bin/python2.7` or whichever version you have installed via MacPorts.

I think the issue is because python installed via pyenv or pre-installed python (shipped with macOS) looks for the libusb library under `/usr` whereas MacPorts installs the library under `/opt/local`.